# iReport формат дата

Tags: postgresql, jasperreports

Проблема такая: База PostgreSql, есть поле в БД - "Дата внесения", и типы данных "date". Делаю отчет с помощью iReports и где, поле "Дата внесения" - отображается время, оно не нужно. То есть, 28.11.17 0:00. Использую iReport-5.6.0. В чем может быть проблема ? Спасибо!

Comment: Так проблема то в чем? В отчете время не отображается? Или наоборот - отображается время, хотя оно не нужно?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis спасибо за внимание, решил проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. В iReport выберите поле дата, (в моем случае Дата внесения) и нажмите правую кнопку мышь, далее выберите "Field pattern".